# How can I map stations for a driving trip?

Tags: usa, planning, driving, automobiles, maps

I have a convention/vacation scheduled soon and I do have a company gas card.  Since it is a company sponsored trip I wanted to map out gas stations for the 16 hour drive.  I was curious to know is there a tool that will map all gas stations for Shell or BP?  I have been using a mixture of MapQuest with Travel Services, Google Maps to pin-point the exit ramp number, and a spreadsheet to list everything within but this is proven to be very timely.

Is there an easier way to have a map of all gas stations of a specific brand along my itinerary?

Comment: Unless you're driving a Ford Excursion or the like you're looking at 2 gas stops at the most.  Is there any point of mapping out Gas Stations?  Also Why not just use something like Gas Buddy application to see what's around based on your location

Comment: well close..  Titan and possibly renting a trailer to buy some new equipment at the show.  Never heard of gas buddy so I will look at that.

Comment: Titan is a guzzler and with trailer you're probably looking at 4 stops one way at the most.  One more thing to consider.  Depending on your route if you're taking toll roads you may not want to get off so the travel service plazas is what you're going to get so Shell or BP may not even be a possibility.

Comment: Don't the two companies provide maps on their websites?

Comment: they do but I still am back to the same issue and having to map each station on the route.  Only alternative right now is gas buddy.

Comment: @Matt_2.0 Do you get that much discount from Shell and BP to use only them?

Comment: I do with shell not BP

Comment: A friend just ordered a road map of Australia with all the gas stations on it. I wouldn't be surprised if similar things exist for the US.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google maps seems to do the trick. You first select your Route description (e.g. [Washington DC - New York](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Washington%20D.C.,%20DC,%20Verenigde%20Staten&daddr=New%20York&hl=nl&sll=40.69834,-74.491425&sspn=0.586171,1.234589&geocode=FQh-UQIdsoRo-ylb5PZa3sa3iTEqXYjUIkVSwg;FXFAbQIdK8KW-yk7CD_TpU_CiTFi_nfhBo8LyA&oq=Washington%20DC&mra=ls&t=m&z=8)). Once you have your route, type shell in the upper search field and Google will show you Shell in the [direct proximity](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Shell&hl=nl&sll=39.800515,-75.520554&sspn=2.375905,4.938354&hq=Shell&t=m&z=8) of your route.

EDIT: The second link doesn't show both the route and shell stations integrated, but this is a screendump on how the result would look

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another site that plots gas stations along a route is [Cost2Drive](http://costtodrive.com) but I don't think it has an option to filter by gas station brand, it just finds the cheapest gas at the refuelling points (based on the range of your car).

Answer (score 1):

I will give one example based on www.shell.com.
If you go on their site at the

> http://www.shell.us/products-services/shell-for-motorists/station-locator.html

you can select the start and the destination and they will provide the list of shell fuel stations on the route.

P.S. The same, for Europe, but pay attention that some shell fuels are not available in all the stations.
For a trip from DE to TR, I had to use the German  and the Austrian sites to map all the stations I needed.